# Java Servlet parameters not transmitting from servlet to .jsp file / IntelliJ

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

This is my first time trying to create a web page with Java Servlet using Tomcat but whenever I try to pass the parameters to the **calculator.jsp** file I get it blank only showing the "Name:" text in calculator.jsp without the ${abc} variable I was trying to transmit from the java class (the "string" text). I cannot figure out what is it wrong.

If someone can help me please because I got stuck and I could not find any solution

Here is the code for **index.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="com.example.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= "Hello World!" %>
</h1>
NAME: <%= ((String)request.getAttribute("abc")) %>
ll :  ${requestScope.abc}

<br/>
<form action="calculator.jsp" method="post">
<button type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**calculator.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" import="com.example.AirlineReservation.HelloServlet" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
NAME: <%= ((String)request.getAttribute("abc")) %>
ll :  ${requestScope.abc}
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloServlet.java**

```
package com.example.AirlineReservation;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name="/calculator")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Testing!";
    }
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String s="string";
        request.setAttribute("abc",s);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/calculator.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    }
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the values from the scope you put it on, in this instance, the requestscope

try this `${requestScope.abc}`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use:

```
 request.getAttribute("abc")
```

or with scriplet

```
<%= request.getAttribute("abc") %>
```

Comment: tried it and it seems I got a 'null' value

Answer (score 0):

You have several small errors in your code:

1. Your form is submitted using `POST` (you specified `method="post"`), therefore your servlet should override the `doPost` method instead of the `doGet` method,
2. You bind your servlet to `/calculator.jsp`, which means that `getRequestDispatcher("/calculator.jsp").forward(request, response)` will dispatch the request to the servlet itself recursively until a `StackOverflowError` is thrown. Bind your servlet to another URI, e.g.:

```
@WebServlet("/calculator")
```

or move your JSP file (`/WEB-INF/calculator.jsp` is a good choice for JSP pages which should not be directly accessed from the web).

3. The `action="/calculator.jsp"` attribute of your form is interpreted as an absolute URI path (relative to the server's root URL, e.g. `http://example.com`). The address of your servlet on the other hand is relative to the context path (e.g. `http://example.com/app_name`). Therefore your form is not submitted to your servlet. Use a relative path in the `action` parameter:

```html
<form action="calculator" method="post">
```

**Remark:** Your EL expression `${abc}` is actually correct. According to the [resolution rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68199629/11748454) for EL expressions the server will look for the "abc" attribute in the page, request, session and application contexts. Therefore it will have the same effect as [Schwencke's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68199629/11748454) `${requestScope.abc}` EL expression or [anish sharma's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68199876/11748454) `<%= request.getAttribute("abc") %>` scriplet expression.

Comment: I did what you have suggested but still it is not working. Maybe could you show me exactly what to change on my code?

Comment: Can you update your code to the current version?

Comment: I did it now but now i get "Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." when accessing "calculator.jsp"

Comment: If you moved `calculator.jsp` to the `WEB-INF` folder, you need to modify the `getDispatcher` call accordingly: `getDispatcher("/WEB-INF/calculator.jsp")`.